# projAPI (GIS library) heap overflow

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, overflow, gis

I'm trying to use the projAPI (http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/ProjAPI) for calculating projections. Sadly, the Documentation is...well...not that good. Also, I'm not that good in C++ programming. Project setup in VisualStudio is some rocket science. anyways, settings are as follows:

- VC++ Directories => Include Directories => added the include dir of the lib
- VC++ Directories => Library Directories => added the lib dir, containing the .lib 
  files
- Linker => Input => Addit. Dependencies => added "proj.lib" and "proj_i.lib"

project is containing one cpp for testing purposes:

```
#include "../include/proj_api.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    projPJ projection;
    projection = pj_init_plus("+proj=merc +ellps=clrk66 +lat_ts=33");
}
```

...compiling like a charm...

---

When coming to `pj_init_plus`, it crashes:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...cuments\visual studio 2012\Projects\testLib\Debug\testLib.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c
Line: 1322

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
```

ignore brings up a second error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...cuments\visual studio 2012\Projects\testLib\Debug\testLib.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c
Line: 1328

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
```

...the main problem is: where is the error? did i fail at compiling the library? *OR* did i fail my project setup?

---

**compiling the library:**

=> run *VCVARS32.BAT* from visual studio tree, then

```
$cd to the downloaded directory
$nmake /f makefile.vc
$nmake /f makefile.vc install-all
```

checked the *C:\PROJ* Directory: everything is there, copied the lib and include directories over to my project and tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i got it working. Obviously the problem just occurs in debug mode. I switched to release mode, and it works.

my guess would be that the lib triggers a function that somehow kills the debug hook...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it expects a true heap pointer, try allocating a pointer with enough space for your string (remember the extra null byte!), strcpy to that, pass that.

Comment: should have answered myself, but the problem obviously vanishes in release mode...